# I have php-script and second php-script called in

Tags: php, request-uri

I have php-script and second php-script called in.

> 1. www.foo.bar/cat/opop.php
> 2. www.foo.bar/fb.php

on page /cat/opop.php there is a button and he is called other php script /fb.php

in /fb.php me need use track uri but it should give this link **www.foo.bar/cat/opop.php**

if i use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in /fb.php - its back `www.foo.bar/fb.php` but i need to track `www.foo.bar/cat/opop.php`

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Though, I think you're using the wrong index in `$_SERVER` - I think you're looking for `'HTTP_REFERER'` and not `'REQUEST_URI'`.

Comment: Is the button you talked about an HTML link?

Comment: yep HTTP_REFERER is good, but if /fb.php is a form, when i click submit HTTP_REFERER change to www.foo.bar/fb.php

Comment: As per your description, you might need to track previous page accessed by user. In PHP, you can use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] command to access the same.

Let me know if it works for you or not.